# I am getting the error "Error in if (first) { : the condition has length > 1" when my condition is a length of 1 in R

Tags: r, if-statement, mailmerge, flextable

For this task I need to add rows to a flextable object if a single observation in my first row is a certain string. If the string is "blue" I need to add data from one data set. If it's "brown" I need to add from a different data set. Most of the time I don't need to append these rows, but there are some cases I do. I end up needing this function to produce ten tables throughout a document running my_function(ARG = 1) through my_function(ARG = 10). Is there a better way to do this?

```
my_condition = starwars[1,6]
length(starwars[1,6])
my_condition %in% c("blue","brown")

my_function = function(ARG){
  
  ft = flextable(starwars %>% filter(height>ARG*60))
  
  if(my_condition %in% c("blue","brown")){
    # nested if statement
    if(my_condition == "blue"){ # assigning which table to pull data from based off of eye color
      ft = flextable::add_body_row(ft,list(mtcars[ARG,2],"",""))
    }else{
      ft = flextable::add_body_row(ft,list(cars[ARG,2],"",""))
    }
    ft = ft %>% 
      bold(i = 1) %>%
      italic(i = 1) %>%
      fontsize(i = 1, size = 16)
  }
}

my_function(ARG = 3)
```

I got the following error:
Error in if (first) { : the condition has length > 1
Called from: add_rows.fpstruct(x[[i]], nrows, first = first)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to explicitly add `values` in your `flextable::add_body_row()` function:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(flextable)

my_condition = starwars[1,6]
length(starwars[1,6])
my_condition %in% c("blue","brown")

my_function = function(ARG){
  
 
  
  ft = flextable(starwars %>% filter(height>ARG*60))
  
  if(my_condition %in% c("blue","brown")){
    # nested if statement
    if(my_condition == "blue"){ # assigning which table to pull data from based off of eye color
      ft = flextable::add_body_row(ft, values = list(mtcars[ARG,2],"",""))
    }else{
      ft = flextable::add_body_row(ft, values = list(cars[ARG,2],"",""))
    }
    ft = ft %>% 
      bold(i = 1) %>%
      italic(i = 1) %>%
      fontsize(i = 1, size = 16)
  }
}

my_function(ARG = 3)
```